# How to show an input box on selecting a particular radio in a radio drop down menu in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My drop down menu of radios is like this:

```
<form id="productlist" onchange="">
<label class="radio">
<input  type="radio" class="region_id" id="product" value="prod1" name="region" onclick="someFunction()">Product_id 1
</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="region_id" id="product" value="prod2" name="region" onclick="someFunction()">Product_id 2
</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="region_id" id="product" value="" name="region" onclick="someFunction()">Manual Product   </label>
```

This form offers user to select a particular product from drop down list. But I want to add the feature of entering product id manually by user. That would be done by 3rd radio. Means if user selects 3rd radio, it should open a text box with submit button through which user will enter the manual product id. 
Also that entered value should be accessible by **"someFunction()"** which I am calling in **"onclick"** event. Ideally (in first 2 radios) in **"someFunction()"** definition I can access the value of selected radio by using **"this.value"**. How'd I do it in the case of the 3rd radio which would be accepting the manual product id by using an input box?

I am new to javascript. Can you please help me doing this.

Comment: If third radio opens input type text use DOM.innerHTML and u get value which would be written in input by user.

Comment: Please create a fiddle so that it would be nice to understand your problem here. And one more all the checkboxes have same id in your HTML , You can't have same id for different elements in the same page.

Comment: I made an example for you . https://jsfiddle.net/bke6Lf1v/

Answer (score 0):

The below code might help :-

```
 <html>
        <head>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function show() { 
            document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'block'
            }
            function hide() { 
            document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none'; 
            document.getElementById('submit').style.display = 'none'
                            }
          </script>
        </head>
        <body>        
          <form name="radios">
            <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="H" onclick="hide();"/>A 
            <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="L" onclick="hide();"/>B 
            <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="LL" onclick="show();"/>C
            <TEXTAREA id="area" style="display: none;" NAME="data" ROWS=10 COLS=50></TEXTAREA>   
            <INPUT TYPE=submit value="submit" id="submit" style="display:none" onclick="show();"/>
          </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a div that hide and show the input and submit button element.

```
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

Initially it will be hidden when you click the third radio button it is shown and you can type in your id here.Once you enter some id into the text box and click on the first two radio button , you just need to get the value of that input element by it's id.Same can be done when you hot the submit button as well.

```
<form id="productlist" onchange="">
    <label class="radio">

      <input  type="radio" class="region_id" id="product" value="prod1" name="region" onclick="someFunction()">Product_id 1
    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" class="region_id" id="product" value="prod2" name="region" onclick="someFunction()">Product_id 2
    </label>
    <br>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" class="region_id" id="thirdChk" value="" name="region" onclick="someFunction()">Manual Product   
    </label>

    <div class="hidden" id="manualProductIdContainer">
        <input type="text" id="productId" placeholder="Enter product id">
        <button type="button" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>    
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#thirdChk', function() {
            $('#manualProductIdContainer').removeClass('hidden');
        });
        $(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function() {
            var productId = $('#productId').val();
            if(productId){
              alert(productId);
            }
            else{
              alert("please enter something in the textbox")
            }
        })

    });

    function someFunction() {
        var productId = $('#productId').val();
        if(){
            alert(productId);
        }           
    }
</script>
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/sarojsasmal/Lehkfkuq/8/

Comment: @kutta ,I don't know why i am unable to add a link. You can copy the link and paste in to check this out.

Comment: I have used jquery for simplicity but the same can also be achieved without using Jquery

Answer (score 0):

I made a bin on the basis of your requirement.

Javascript

```
(function() {
  var output=document.getElementById('output');
  var getCustomValue;
  this.someFunction = function(id) {

    if (id === undefined || id==="") {
      document.querySelector('#custom-wrapper').style.display = 'block';

 output.innerHTML=getCustomValue;

    } else {
      document.querySelector('#custom-wrapper').style.display = 'none';

      console.log(id);
      output.innerHTML=id
    }
  }
  this.setCustomerValue = function() {
    getCustomValue = document.querySelector('#custom-value').value;
    document.querySelector('#product3').setAttribute("value",getCustomValue);

    document.querySelector('#custom-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
   output.innerHTML=getCustomValue
  }
})();
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <form id="productlist">
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" class="region_id" id="product1" value="prod1" name="region" onclick="someFunction(this.value)">Product_id 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" class="region_id" id="product2" value="prod2" name="region" onclick="someFunction(this.value)">Product_id 2
    </label>
    <label class="radio">
      <input type="radio" class="region_id" id="product3" value="" name="region" onclick="someFunction()">Manual Product
      <div id="custom-wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="custom-value" value="">
        <input type="button" onclick="setCustomerValue()" value="Add Product" />
      </div>
    </label>

    <div id="output">

    </div>
</body>
```

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/cexecegowi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)